# Ошмбка в javascript

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Раньше всё работало нормально, и тут не понятно из за чего ввылезает ошибка

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Вот сам код:

```
async function create(addres, decs, price, pictures) { 
//docInfo.content[opew] = { image: "data:image/jpg;base64," + base_mass[this67] }
var docInfo = {};
addresa = pictures.split(":")
count = addresa.length;
nowfile = 0;
openw = 4;
ban = 0;

var docInfo = {

 info: {
  title: addres,
 },

 pageSize:'A3',
 pageOrientation:'landscape',//'portrait'
 pageMargins:[50,50,30,60],

 header:function(currentPage,pageCount) {
  return {
  }
 },

 content: [

  {
 text: addres,
 fontSize:20,
 alignment:'center'
 //pageBreak:'after'
  },

  {
 text:'Описание:\n' + ' ' + decs,
 style:'header'
 //pageBreak:'before'
  },

  {
 text:'\nЦена: ' + price,
 style:'header'
 //pageBreak:'before'
  }
 ]
}

while(nowfile < count) {
 await $.get("http://192.168.1.108/photos" + addresa[nowfile], function(data) {
  str = "data:image/jpg;base64," + data
  docInfo['content'][openw] = { image: str, alignment: 'center' };
  openw = openw + 1;
  nowfile = nowfile + 1;
});
};
pdfMake.createPdf(docInfo).download(addres + '.pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в отсутствии файла библиотеки